# Making Generics with many types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a chunk of code where sometimes I need to create a new generic type, but with an unknown number of generic parameters.  For example:

```
public object MakeGenericAction(Type[] types)
{
  return typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
}
```

The problem is that if I have more than one Type in my array, then the program will crash.  In the short term I have come up with something like this as a stop-gap.

```
public object MakeGenericAction(Type[] types)
{
  if (types.Length == 1)
  {
    return typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
  }
  else if (types.Length ==2)
  {
    return typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
  }
  ..... And so on....
}
```

This does work, and is easy enough to cover my scenarios, but it seems really hacky.  Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, yes:

```
Type actionType = Expression.GetActionType(types);
```

The problem here though is that you will probably be using DynamicInvoke which is slow.

An `Action<object[]>` then access by index may outperform an `Action<...>` invoked with DynamicInvoke

Comment: Beautiful, elegant solution (or at least as much as reflective generics can be)

Comment: Very Nice.  What would happen if you had more than 16 types in your array?  Other than the code police removing all electronic devices from you.

Comment: @IndigoDelta the cogs will fall out ;p

Comment: Fantastic!  I never would have found that on my own.  I should point out that there is also a 'GetFuncType' in there too.

Comment: @A. R.: Note that as its implementation details GetActionType simply implements the pattern that you proposed; it switches on the number of types in the array and returns `typeof(Action<,,,,,>).MakeGenericType(...)`. It's not magical in any way. If you want to do this for some type other than Action or Func then you'll have to write a similar switch.

Comment: @Eric - yes, but code that *you don't have to maintain* is always slightly magical ;p

Comment: @Marc: Good point. Also, the build script which builds this part of the framework automatically checks to see if new Action types have been added and regenerates the code appropriately, so we have reason to believe that this will continue to give good results even if we add more Action types in the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
Assembly asm = typeof(Action<>).Assembly;
Dictionary<int, Type> actions = new Dictionary<int, Type>;
foreach (Type action in asm.GetTypes())
    if (action.Name == "Action" && action.IsGenericType)
        actions.Add(action.GetGenericArguments().Lenght, action)
```

then you can use the `actions` dictionary to quickly find the right type:

```
public Type MakeGenericAction(Type[] types)
{
  return actions[types.Lenght].MakeGenericType(paramTypes);
}
```