# Making a generic type for Tuples

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, tuples

I've clearly established how to make a generic Tuple as follows when the number of items is known in advance...

```
        Type t = typeof(Tuple<,,>);
        Type[] keys = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(int) };
        Type specific = t.MakeGenericType(keys);
```

but what if the number of objects in the "keys" array is variable? How to you start the ball rolling with the initial assignment to "t"?

Cheers.
Craig

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268958/making-generics-with-many-types/6268982#comment-7317555

Comment: Unfortunately the .NET type system does not support variadic generic types, which is what you really need to solve this problem in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I would have an array of the generic type definitions:

```
Type[] tupleTypes = {
    typeof(Tuple<>),
    typeof(Tuple<,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,>),
    typeof(Tuple<,,,,,,,>),
};
```

You *could* do this in code, but it would be a bit of a pain... probably something like:

```
Type[] tupleTypes = Enumerable.Range(1, 8)
                              .Select(x => Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + x)
                              .ToArray();
```

Or avoiding the array:

```
Type generic = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`" + keys.Length);
Type specific = generic.MakeGenericType(keys);
```

Comment: That's my fall-back for the moment, but I was hoping there would be a way to programatically pick the type with the right arity through reflection..Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: Is the naming of generic types part of the standard, or just what Microsoft happens to do?  Is the type guaranteed to be named things like "Tuple1" and "Tuple2" (with back ticks I don't know how to include in a comment)?  Or could it change in future versions of .NET, or if using another framework implementation like Mono?

Comment: @Darryl: The naming is guaranteed. See ECMA 335 I.10.7.2 for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way of building `tupleTypes` through Tuple.Create:

```
// once
Type[] tupleTypes = typeof(Tuple).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(mi => mi.IsGenericMethod && mi.Name == "Create")
    .Select(mi => mi.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .Distinct() // make sure there is no duplicated return types
    .OrderBy(t => t.GetGenericArguments().Length)
    .ToArray(); // expect start from Tuple<>

// instant type creation
Type tupleType = tupleTypes[types.Length-1].MakeGenericType(types);
```

Of course that expects that class System.Tuple will contain static Create methods that only produces Tuple<...>.